# all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions python

Tags: python

**My Code:**

```
GL_A = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
DB_c = [88]

writer.writerow(numpy.append(GL_A[i],DB_c[j], index))
```

**The Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "<ipython-input-61-16267abc0150>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/cp1/PythonScript/linearregression.py', wdir='C:/Users/cp1/PythonScript')
  File "C:\Users\cp1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\cp1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/cp1/PythonScript/linearregression.py", line 59, in <module>
    writer.writerow(numpy.append(GL_Account_Number[i],DB_clusters[j], index))
  File "C:\Users\cp1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4586, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)    
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

The output that I would like to have is column1 with all elements of GL_A and a column2 with repetition of 88 (DB_c)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did this solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

> The output that I would like to have is column1 with all element of GL_A and a column2 with repetition of 88 (DB_c)

1) Create a new array which is the same length as GL_A which contains the single value in DB_c repeated:

```
GL_A = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
DB_c = [88]
DB_cn = DB_c * len(GL_A)

>>>
DB_cn = [88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88]
```

You will then have two arrays of the same length that can be saved as 2 separate columns.

2) Join both arrays using `zip` to get the output you want:

Altogether:

```
GL_A = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
DB_c = [88]
DB_cn = DB_c * len(GL_A)

import csv

with open('some.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(zip(GL_A,DB_cn))
```

And your file:

```
>>> some.csv Output:

2   88
3   88
4   88
5   88
6   88
7   88
8   88
```

You can add headers to this if you require.